BottomNavigationView height issue - Icons not centered properly
I'm having an issue with my BottomNavigationView where the icons are not vertically centered. In the Android Studio preview, everything looks perfect, but when I run the app on an emulator, the height of the BottomNavigationView is larger, causing the icons to appear above the middle. I'm using Kotlin and XML for my layout.
Here is my layout XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/main_activity_nav" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:itemIconSize="28dp"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_selector"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/nav_item_background"
        app:itemRippleColor="@null"
        app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@null"
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

nav_background.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="100dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>

What I've tried:

Setting a Fixed Height:

I tried setting a fixed height (e.g., 56dp or 72dp) for the BottomNavigationView, but this caused the icons to be cut off and only half-visible.


Ensuring No Padding in Drawable Resources:

I verified that there is no padding set in the drawable resources, such as nav_background.xml, nav_item_selector.xml, and nav_item_background.xml.


Adjusting itemIconSize:

I tried lowering the itemIconSize to see if it makes any difference, but it did not solve the issue.


Maintaining wrap_content Height:

When I set the height to wrap_content, the icons are not centered and appear above the middle.



Android Emulator:

Android Studio Preview:


app:itemIconSize="28dp" is probably going to be at least part of the cause. Generally speaking it's good to try and avoid using fixed dp sizes where possible so that your layouts and items can adapt to different screen sizes and densities

Can android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" be the issue?

It seems like insets related issue, but to tell what exactly causes the issue i would need to see more code, theme properties, additional activity flags, etc...

Issue with Bottom Navigation Bar Overlapping in Android
It's hard to tell without seeing the activity code, so we can only guess based on the screenshot and XML provided. It seems like there is no issue with the XML itself, the icons, or the bottom navigation bar. It's more likely there is an issue with the activity window setup.
This kind of behavior happens if the setDecorFitsSystemWindows is set to false (via enableEdgeToEdge()), which (from the screenshot) looks like your case. The system tries to add padding automatically to prevent overlapping of the system navigation bar (with home/back buttons or the swipe navigation line).
To avoid this, you should handle the insets correctly. There are a couple of ways to do so, depending on your case. I can't suggest an exact solution as I can't see your activity code and don't know why and how the window is set up. However, you may want to look into this documentation: Handling overlaps with edge-to-edge and pay attention to setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener.
Alternatively, even simply setting android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in the activity root may help, but it may break other things, again, depending on window flags in the activity.

Understanding Window Insets
Window insets are basically margins that represent the size of system components like navigation or status bars, back-navigation areas at the left or right of the screen, etc. If not accounted for, your components (like the bottom navigation bar) might be overlapped with system components and make yours unusable.
In your case, the bottom nav bar is not overlapped by the system nav bar because of the margin at the bottom. However, this margin won't work with button navigation like on older Android versions. If you remove the margin at the bottom, your view will be overlapped  And the automatically added padding is intended to ensure that the bottom navigation buttons appear on top of the system nav bar, not behind it.
Solution
To solve this, you need to remove the margin at the bottom and use insets instead:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(
            window.decorView
        ) { v, insets ->
            val windowInsets = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            findViewById<View>(R.id.main).updatePadding(bottom = windowInsets.bottom)

            return@setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener CONSUMED
        }

    }
}

The result:

You can still keep the bottom margin if you want the navbar to be a bit far from the bottom system navigation.
To learn more about insets, also check this video: Handling Window Insets in Android.

Also there is a line cutting the shadow at the bottom, that's because the shadow is cut to the padding. It can be fixed by adding android:clipToPadding="false" to the   "id/main" view.
